# Need help closing sidebar/pull navigation menu when menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive website that contains a navigation slider that is closed (off-screen) by default. This includes a vertical push/pull bar that is always visible on the screen to open and close the menu. The entire navigation slider is fixed on the page with a scrollbar on the menu.

When the menu is open on smaller devices, it takes up 100% of the viewport width. To accommodate this, I also add a top margin to the body content of 100vh to push it off the bottom. When a user clicks a menu item, it should take them to the link and automatically close the menu. I'm attempting to do this with an event listener on the menu items. If clicked, it removes the `active` class that controls the display when the menu is open. Currently, it takes the user to the link, but does not close the menu.

I know that the event listener works (to some degree) because if I change the body to `display:none` instead of `margin-top:vh`, clicking the menu item closes the menu, but, of course, it does not take the user to the link. I am aware that this is because the body content was displayed until after the link was clicked, which is why I'm trying to handle this with `margin-top` instead of `display`.

What am I missing? I've searched for an answer to this, but I can't seem to find anything that addresses this particular issue. I am pretty inexperienced in JavaScript, so any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mquery = window.matchMedia("(max-width:767.98)");
  $('#toggle-bar').on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
  });
  if (mquery.matches) {
    $('.menu-item').on('click', function() {
      $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: calc(-100% + 25px);
  /*to keep .sidebar-toggle in the view*/
}

.sidebar.active {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.sidenav {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebar-toggle {
  width: 25px;
}

.sidebar #navpush {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar.active #navpush {
  display: inline;
}

.sidebar.active #navpull {
  display: none;
}

.body-content {
  padding: 15px;
}

.sidebar.active~.body-content {
  margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container body-wrapper">
  <aside class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
    <nav class="sidenav">
      <ul id="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#section1" class="menu-item">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sect1nav" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">Section 1</a>
          <ul id="sect1nav" class="collapse submenu">
            <li><a href="#section2a" class="menu-item">Section 2A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2b" class="menu-item">Section 2B</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section3" class="menu-item">Section 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="toggle-bar" id="toggle-bar">
      <div id="nav-toggle">
        <span id="navpush">&laquo;</span>
        <span id="navpull">&raquo;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <div class="container body-content">
    <div id="section1">
      <h2>Section 1 Title</h2>
      <div>
        <!-- Content -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
      <h2>Section 2 Title</h2>
      <div id="section2a">
        <h3>Section 2A Title</h3>
        <div>
          <!-- Content -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="section2b">
        <h3>Section 2B Title</h3>
        <div>
          <!-- Content -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="section3">
      <h2>Section 2 Title</h2>
      <div>
        <!-- Content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by lack of units in the media query:

Fixed code (note the addition of "px" at the end):

```
var mquery = window.matchMedia("(max-width:767.98px)");
```

**Pre-edit:** Your HTML markup does not contain elements with ID "sidebar" (#sidebar) or "toggle-bar" (#toggle-bar).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out... a result of condensing my code for the snippet. Edited to fix. The IDs are present in my source code.

Comment: Thanks, Mat Sz! That completely fixed it, and I can't believe I overlooked that. It just goes to show that sometimes you need an extra pair of eyes. Thanks for being my eyes today!

Comment: @T.Carano On a side note: you should make sure to check the media query on resize events if you'd like for it to be 100% responsive.

Comment: Thanks, Mat Sz. I will do that. On larger size screens, the sidebar will be open by default and only take a portion of the screen. The only time the sidebar should close is when the user clicks to close it, which is why I limited the width for the function to fire. I will check the media query to ensure that it still fires (when necessary) when screens have been resized. Thanks for the tip.